# margin-left для полосы прокрутки в Chrome

Tags: html, css, прокрутка

Имеется полоса прокрутки:

```css
#parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#child {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: teal;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f6f5f3;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #c1c1c1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Хочу сделать, чтобы между полосой прокрутки и контентом (блок `#child`) было расстояние в `2px`. По сути хочу написать `::-webkit-scrollbar { margin-left: 2px; }`. Так не работает. Пробовал добавить `padding-right: 2px` к элементу `#parent`, но тогда если полосы прокрутки нет (то есть в блоке `#child` мало содержимого (в примере высота `#child` фиксирована, но в реальном проекте зависит от содержимого)), то будут лишние `2px` пустого места. Как добавить расстояние `2px` между полосой прокрутки и блоком `#child`?

### Обновление:

У блока `#parent` имеется свойство `overflow-y: auto;`. То есть появится полоса прокрутки или нет зависит от высоты блока `#child`. В примере высота `#child` фиксирована, однако в реальном проекте зависит от содержимого (там динамически подгружаемый текст, много текста => появится полоса прокрутки, мало текста => не появится). Это всё к тому, что если полосы прокрутки нет, то решение **не должно** влиять на отображение. То есть  хочется добавить `2px` свободного места между контентом и полосой прокрутки, если полоса прокрутки есть, и ничего не добавлять, если её нет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
#parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#child {
  height: 500px;
  background: teal;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;  // 8px (ширина полосы прокрутки) + 2px (расстояние между полосой прокрутки и контентом)
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f6f5f3;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #c1c1c1;
  border-left: solid 2px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это ведь по сути не отличается от `#parent { padding-right: 2px }` и, соответственно, имеет те же самые проблемы. Посмотри, пожалуйста, обновление вопроса.

Comment: еще как вариант                                                                                  
:::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #c1c1c1;
  border-left: solid 2px #fff;
}

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, так всё работает.

Comment: Если правильно понял, `border-right: solid 5px #fff;` у `#child` осталось от первого варианта решения, и его надо удалить.

Answer (score 2):

Может, не так понял, но возможно, это имелось ввиду.
Использована функция calc.

```css
#parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#child {
  height: 500px;
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  background: teal;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f6f5f3;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #c1c1c1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это ведь по сути не отличается от `#parent { padding-right: 2px }` и, соответственно, имеет те же самые проблемы. Посмотри, пожалуйста, обновление вопроса.